# QUITE AND MUCH + SUPERLATIVE ADJECTIVES

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, superlatives

It´s possible to use "much" and "quite" as adverbs of degree in front of superlative adjectives?

Comment: I think that Johnnie Walker is much the best supermarket whisky.

Comment: No:
"He's quite the best climber" is wrong, but:
"He's not quite the best climber" is good.
The latter implies that he's still a good climber.

I'm not sure how to use "much" with superlatives... I want to say it's odd

Comment: @Riolku - "He's quite the best climber" is perfectly acceptable, but it uses _quite_ in its other sense of _entirely_, not _rather_.

Comment: I think that Gilbeys is quite the best supermarket gin.

Comment: This is a BrE / AmE difference.  AmE speakers don't use **quite** in the way that @KateBunting has indicated.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Makes sense; I very rarely, if ever, see "quite" used that way in AmE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can, in British English, use 'much the' and 'quite the' before superlatives.

**We can use 'much' before superlatives, with the meaning of 'by far'.**

If something is much the best out of a group, it is not just a bit better than the others, it is very much better than any of them. If I am much the fastest in a race, I am way ahead of the pack.

> much   adverb     by a great amount
>
> *much the best/most interesting etc* British English

We can qualify 'much' with 'very' for emphasis, e.g. 'My son is very much the tallest boy in his class'.

[Much (Longman Dictionary)](http://ldoceonline.com/dictionary/much)

**We can use 'quite' before superlatives, for emphasis, with the meaning 'definitely', 'undoubtedly', etc.**

> quite the best, worst, etc.
> mainly UK
> formal old-fashioned
> used for emphasis:
>
> *It was quite the worst dinner I have ever had.*

[Quite (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quite)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the comments:

Both words can be used this way, but not in all regions (yes in British usage, no in American): "This is quite the worst day I've ever had." "This is much the best house in town."

Note that the "the" is required in this construction; you can't say "this is much best."

Note: You can use both words with *non*-superlative adjectives of comparison freely, in any region as far as I know, sometimes with or without "the," depending on the construction:

> These pants are much the worse for wear.

> I feel quite the same as I did yesterday.

> He is much taller than his brother.

You can also, in any region as far as I know, use "quite" when *negating* superlatives:

> This car is not quite the fastest.

Comment: I'd like to add that in the case of "quite," the word "the" is still added after it. That is, you cannot say something is "quite fastest" or "much best."

Comment: We can, in British English, at least, use 'much' with superlatives, with the meaning of 'by far'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Wow, I didn't realize; I sincerely thought your first comment about the whisky was in jest! Edited.

Comment: If something is 'not quite the best, fastest, most delicious, etc', at least in Bristish usage, that means it's still pretty good, fast, or delicious, but _just behind_ whatever was judged the winner.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I never joke about anything as serious as whisky.